# transfer to particular address on function call

Tags: contract-development, erc-20

How can I make a function that sends balance of the contract to a particular address?
I want it to be hardcoded at the time of contract deployment.

Also, how can I trigger a function if the contract receives money from the same address?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was not sure if the question if for ethers balance or erc20 tokens, so I just did it to work with ethers balance:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Ownable {
    address public owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender == owner)
            _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public onlyOwner {
        if (newOwner != address(0)) owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract TestContract is Ownable {
    address payable public fundsReceiver;
    uint256 public dummyValue;
    
    constructor (address payable _fundsReceiver) public payable {
        fundsReceiver = _fundsReceiver;
    }
    
    function changeReceiver(address payable _receiver) public onlyOwner {
        fundsReceiver = _receiver;
    }
    
    function withdrawToReceiver() public onlyOwner {
        if (address(this).balance > 0) {
            fundsReceiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }
    
    function executeIfReceiver () internal {
        dummyValue = now;
    }
    
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function () payable external {
        if (address(msg.sender) == fundsReceiver) {
            executeIfReceiver();
        }
    }
}

contract Send {
    constructor () payable public {
        
    }
    
    function sendtest(address payable _address) payable public {
       address(_address).call.value(msg.value)('');
    }
}
```

- Added Ownable contract so only the contract owner has access to methods `changeReceiver` and `withdrawToReceiver`
- Method `executeIfReceiver` is getting called only if the eth amount sender is the address selected by the contract owner
- Method `withdrawToReceiver` is withdrawing all the contract eth balance to the selected receiver

If you wish the following logic to work the same with erc20 tokens, all you have to do is connect contract `TestContract` with the interface of the erc20 contract and edit method `withdrawToReceiver` to work with erc20 methods `balanceOf` and `transfer`.

However with erc20 tokens you cannot have fallback method where you can bind additional logic whenever the contract receive erc20 tokens. What you could do is build another method where inside of it users can send erc20 tokens only to that particular contract and below that you can add the additional logic which should execute if the contract received the erc20 tokens successfully.

Hope this helps.

***Edit:***

```
contract TestContract is Ownable {
    address payable public fundsReceiver;
    address public fundsSender;
    
    constructor (address payable _fundsReceiver, address _fundsSender) public payable {
        fundsReceiver = _fundsReceiver;
        fundsSender = _fundsSender;
    }
    
    function changeReceiver(address payable _receiver) public onlyOwner {
        fundsReceiver = _receiver;
    }
    
    function changeSender(address _fundsSender) public onlyOwner {
        fundsSender = _fundsSender;
    }
    
    function withdrawToReceiver() internal {
        if (address(this).balance > 0) {
            fundsReceiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
        }
    }
    
    function getBalance() public view returns(uint256) {
        return address(this).balance;
    }
    
    function () payable external {
        if (address(msg.sender) == fundsSender) {
            withdrawToReceiver();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for this, however I needed it to call a function or withdrawToReceiver when it receives any ETH from the address which we mention. Is that possible?

Comment: I added an edit of contract ```TestContract``` where all the contract ETH amount is sent to ```fundsReceiver``` if ```fundsSender``` is the one who is sending ETH to the contract. If this is what you wanted please accept the answer with green check.

Comment: Hey @Miroslavm, I am getting one error on last function. https://prnt.sc/uo9yel